# Django: convert DateField to string using DATE_FORMAT

Tags: python, django

I want to convert a Django `DateField` to a string according to the `DATE_FORMAT` as specified in `settings.py`, where I have a certain date format hard-coded.  Can it be done without specifying a second (and at best superflous) date format for, e.g., `strftime`?

Comment: Have you tried calling `str()` on the date field?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to call some function in your view / some other code and have it automatically use the `DATE_FORMAT` from your settings?

Comment: @JohnGordon: this does not follow the `DATE_FORMAT` I have set in `settings.py`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`django.utils.formats.date_format` (Source Code [GitHub])](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f10c52afabac25f2c10aca26d32dbe7e0e46082e/django/utils/formats.py#L146) to do what you want. Note that this is undocumented and appears to be only used by the template tags / templating system and hence may change in future versions.

```
from django.utils.formats import date_format


# Signature of the function
# date_format(value, format=None, use_l10n=None)
date_string = date_format(some_date_object)
```